# controlling multi-boot through python

Tags: python, networking, multiboot

I wrote a bunch of `Python` scripts that allow me reboot, shutdown, and wake on LAN using `Python`.
The `wake on LAN` script, for example, uses the network to send a packet which initializes the boot of a machine.
The problem is: I'm running some performance tests, and I have 12 different versions of Windows installed in a single desktop (7, 8 and Blue, both x86 and x64)
So when the boot starts, comes in the option of choosing which machine to boot. Once I get this figure out, then I'm pretty much done.
Is there any python library, or anything that can be run through `Python` that can control to which machine to boot?
For example, suppose we have in the startup boot the installs `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.
Is there a way which I can retrieve a list of those options, and then choose boot `B` to start, for example? Other than that, I have the whole application figured out.
Here is the script for the `Wake on LAN`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# wol.py

import socket
import struct

def wake_on_lan(macaddress):
    """ Switches on remote computers using WOL. """

    # Check macaddress format and try to compensate.
    if len(macaddress) == 12:
        pass
    elif len(macaddress) == 12 + 5:
        sep = macaddress[2]
        macaddress = macaddress.replace(sep, '')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect MAC address format')

    # Pad the synchronization stream.
    data = ''.join(['FFFFFFFFFFFF', macaddress * 20])
    send_data = '' 

    # Split up the hex values and pack.
    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
        send_data = ''.join([send_data,
                             struct.pack('B', int(data[i: i + 2], 16))])

    # Broadcast it to the LAN.
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.sendto(send_data, ('<broadcast>', 7))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Use macaddresses with any seperators.
    wake_on_lan('0F:0F:DF:0F:BF:EF')
    wake_on_lan('0F-0F-DF-0F-BF-EF')
    # or without any seperators.
    wake_on_lan('0F0FDF0FBFEF')
```

[WOL](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/358449-wake-on-lan/)

Comment: this is clever what you have here. but i am not sure you are able to send keyboard commands over network at this stage of the computer booting. If it were possible, i would imagine it to be something that needs to be enabled in your BIOS.